# Git стал самостоятельно именовать фиксации

Tags: git, git-merge

Раньше, делая `git merge iss55` всегда выкидывало в Vim для задания названия фиксации (commit). И вдруг Git стал сам именовать фиксации так:

> Merge branch 'iss55' into dev

В чём может быть дело? Я не хочу писать `… -m "…`, хочу, чтобы открывался Vim.

Comment: Да вроде наоборот, всегда автоматическое сообщение было... Попробуй автокоммит отключить?

Comment: по умолчанию вроде бы редактор не показывается, уже довольно давно. `git config --global core.mergeoptions --edit` может помочь.

Comment: @akp может у вас алиас назначен на `merge`?

Comment: @akp ещё если в локальном репозитории конфиг `core.mergeoptions` выставлен, то глобальный не влияет. Что показывает `git config --local --list`?

Comment: @akp отключить автокоммит можно с помощью `git config --global core.mergeoptions --no-commit`, но вам тогда каждый раз придется вторым действием выполнять `git commit`, что более трудоемко.

Comment: @akp ставите `@` – появляется список-подсказка.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65465/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-akp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте ключ `--edit`, чтобы команда `merge` всегда открывала редактор для сообщения коммита:

```
git merge --edit iss55
```

Даже если где-то в глобальной или локальной конфигурации настроено `core.mergeoptions --no-edit`, явно указанный ключ будет иметь приоритет.

Для удобства можно назначить алиас (псевдоним):

```
git config --global alias.me 'merge --edit'
```

Comment: У этого автора вопросов проблема с чтением литературы как я понимаю ;) Есть хорошая мудрость про рыбу и голодного, так вот я бы не стал тратить время на разжевывание в этих конкретных случаях.

Comment: @0andriy я не раз замечал, что документация к Git довольно сложна и запутанна. Её явно писал разработчик, подразумевающий, что все читатели знают теорию графов и комфортно себя чувствуют в командной строке. Такое заблуждение называется [проклятием знания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). По этому поводу есть таже шутка: генератор случайных manpages https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/

Comment: @0andriy я лично когда-то пытался научиться работать с ветками по документации `man git-branch; man git-merge; man git-cherry-pick`. Но только больше запутывался и пугался от сложности. А уверенно пользоваться стал, когда прошёл курс на https://learngitbranching.js.org/

Comment: @0andriy но я учту ваше замечание про рыбу. Буду добавлять подсказки, как в следующий раз искать информацию самостоятельно.

Comment: Ну даже не знаю, документация не ахти (хотя я ей пользуюсь), я же ссылаюсь на ProGit.